# Advancing data frame calculations by integer

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write some more concise/efficient code for a section of data. I have a data frame that has a repeating pattern of data, see below for a sample.

```
#Simple Sample Data
 Date_2012<-c(NA,NA,NA)
 X2<-c(1,1,1)
 X3<-c(2,2,2)
 XNA<-c(NA,NA,NA)
 Date_2013<-c(NA,NA,NA)
 X6<-c(3,3,3)
 X7<-c(4,4,4)
 df<-data.frame(Date_2012,X2,X3,XNA,Date_2013,X6,X7)

> df
  Date_2012 X2 X3 XNA Date_2013 X6 X7 XNA
1        NA  1  2  NA        NA  3  4 NA
2        NA  1  2  NA        NA  3  4 NA
3        NA  1  2  NA        NA  3  4 NA
```

I want to do some calculations with X2 & X3 and then advance to X6 & X7 and do the same calculations. These columns used for calculations will always be a set number away from each other, and I am wondering what to use to advance the calculation, whether it be a for loop or something else.

```
#Calcuations, how to make this efficient? (loop?)
Calc<-df[,2]*df[,3]
Total2012<-sum(Calc)

Calc2<-df[,6]*df[,7]
Total2013<-sum(Calc2)

#Then continuously update the "Totals"     
Totals<-c(Total2012,Total2013)

# Desired Result
> Totals
[1]  6 36 #.......... with results being added until columns exhausted
```

**Overall I would like to keep advancing through the data frame (maybe by integer?) and doing these calculations while updating the Totals list, how would I do this effeciently?**

I thought of using a function to control the `df[A]*df[b]`, but there are too many columns to make this concise, as I would have to call the function many times.

Is there a better way I am missing?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the `XNA` column?

Comment: @userR just to help separate the columns a little more, I have blank columns in my data, but not really important to the question.

Comment: So would there be `XNA` columns right after every `X1`, `X2` columns?

Comment: Yes, the formatting is Date, Data1, Data2, NA, Date, Data3, Data4, NA, Date, ....... and so on. @useR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do something like this using `sapply`:

```
Totals = sapply((1:ncol(df))[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)], 
                function(x) sum(df[,x]*df[,x+1]))

# [1]  6 36
```

This creates a sequence of column indices that is fed into `sapply` to calculate the column sum of the product of consecutive columns.